# How to configure a VSCode Python venv to work without modifications on Linux and Windows?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

Python venv module creates different structures in Windows and Linux.

Our Python project is developed in Windows and Linux machines. We use VSCode and To standardize the development the `.vscode/settings.json` configuration file is commited to the repository. We develop under a virtual environment created by Python standard `venv` module and all our projects create the venv under the directory `.venv`.

The main Python extension configuration for VSCode is the interpreter path. In Windows the venv interpreter executable is under `.venv/Scripts/python`, but in Linux it is under `.venv/bin/python`.

How do I configure VSCode (or my project) to make it work without modifications under Windows and Linux?

Comment: That seems kind of limiting, because different OSs (and users!) use different shells. Have you tried starting VS Code from the shell, after activating the environment there?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the main problem is that we usually develop using the SSH Remote extension. We also have an automation to create the venv and we want to use it in prd and dev.